# Using hooks with object or single value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I can't find answer so, this is my question. What is better practice using hooks like that with spread operator?

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({name: 'John', email: 'john@john.pl'})
setUser(prev => {...prev, name: 'New name'})
```

Or making state per properties?

```
const [name, setName] = useState('John')
setName('New name')

const [email, setEmail] = useState('john@john.pl')
setEmail('New email')
```

What is better option and why?

Answer (score 1):

please read this info in react docs.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-one-or-many-state-variables

The both approaches has pros and cons.

Some important hightligts from docs:

> we recommend to split state into multiple state variables based on
>   which values tend to change together.
>
> Both putting all state in a single useState call, and having a
>   useState call per each field can work. Components tend to be most
>   readable when you find a balance between these two extremes, and group
>   related state into a few independent state variables. If the state
>   logic becomes complex, we recommend managing it with a reducer or a
>   custom Hook.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly the 2nd one since you don't need to pass around the whole user state on each state update but just the user's name or email. Try to keep it simple where ever you can.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's better to have simple state when using hooks, since `setState()` works a bit different than `this.setState()` in class components - it not merges changes, but just update those:

```js
// in class component
this.setState({ name: 'Hello' }); // update only name field of state

// in functional component
setState({ name: 'Hello' });  // sets { name: 'Hello' } as new state
```

For complex state you can use `useReducer()` hook.

Answer (score 0):

hooks state easy to use than setState. You can use hooks with spread operator like this

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({name: 'John', email: 'john@john.pl'});
setUser({...user, name: 'New name'});
```